# Why is Entity Framework core loading entity's relations without adding include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF core in a .net core project. After fetching data from ef context, the object's entity's (one-to-many etc...) are automatically loaded.

Here's my code:

```cs
 public TimeSheetActivity Get(int id)
 {
     DataSets.TimeSheetActivity dbActivity = db.TimeSheetActivities
                                               .Include(k => k.ProjectFile)
                                               .Include(k => k.MeasurementUnit)
                                               .Include(k => k.TypeOfWork)
                                               .Include(k => k.TimeSheetProject)
                                               .FirstOrDefault(k => k.ID == id);

     return dbActivity == null ? null : _mapper.Map<TimeSheetActivity>(dbActivity);
 }


public Project GetActivityProject(int id)
{
    //db.SaveChanges();

    TimeSheetActivity activity = Get(id);

    if (activity == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var dbTimeSheetProject = db.TimeSheetProjects.First(k => k.ID == activity.TimeSheetProjectId);

    var dbProject = db.Projects.First(k => k.ID == dbTimeSheetProject.ProjectId);
    // PROBLEM HERE >> dbProject is loading all entities related
    return _mapper.Map<Project>(dbProject);
}
```

The problem is marked above and commented in `Projects` context, here's the project class:

```cs
public class Project
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }


        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual Project Parent { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Project> Activities { get; set; }
        public virtual List<TimeSheetProject> TimeSheetProjects { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ProjectFile> ProjectFiles { get; set; }

    }
```

Debugging capture:

[image: Debug]

Comment: You cannot rely on the Watch window in this case. Things are loaded on demand, and watching it, is a demand. So it is impossible to see if something is loaded or not. If you want to be sure, better check the query, sent to the SQL-Server, to see what is included.

Comment: When you use `virtual ` keyword that means EF load company LazyLoad

Comment: @Holger i'm loading watch after compiling the line-of-code, so it will result with the actual db object result. plus, automapper threw an exception because it was unable to cast all populated entities..

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour i removed the virtual keyword, nothing changed

Comment: No, it's impossible to watch any "actual db result", the watch window itself is sending further queries to your database, and reloads everything you want to see. Even then you "break all threads"  the debugging windows can run your code.
If the objects are loaded in one query (with the include) or in many queries(with lazy loading) you can only see in the SQL commands.
Do you want to enforce or avoid loading of all objects ?
Looks like you enforce with include, everything is loaded, and than you complain everything is loaded.

Comment: afaik, using list will immediately execute the db queries, it much better to use `IEnumerable` instead, but perhaps there are some things here, can you also provide the relevant part of snapshot?

Comment: @keysl I also changed the lists to IEnumerable, but its not only a list problem. single properties like `Comapny` and `Department` are also populated .

Comment: @keysl you meant by relevant this? https://i.ibb.co/Fk1KbW6/Debug.png

Comment: I meant the DataContext, and your DataContextModelSnapshot. I peek my old net core project and it doesn't load navigation properties unless you include it so I think somewhere on the configuration is causing this

Comment: @keysl here's my context file https://drive.google.com/file/d/13R-hzPNYzdsHNjKDK2YsFRN_009n_ndk/view?usp=sharing   Note that i also use include in other methods to be able to load navigation properties. but i'm having problems with this block of code

Comment: I think you really need to run a SQL profiler against your database, this should give you much greater clarity as to what's happening, if it's still not clear then you can add the relevant parts of the trace to your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding @cristi71000 answer, that was the case. my solution was adding `AsNoTracking()` as the following:

```cs
var dbProject = db.Projects.AsNoTracking()...
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem is this (excerpt from documentation):

> Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading

Comment: Interesting this could be a case

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue, i fixed it by adding an additional linq expression asNoTracking()

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem